# What is Concurrently error in AWS in start query execution operation and how to solve it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am currently  facing issue in the project where S3 buckets contain avg 50 tables and after running glue job I see this following error. I think its not the issue of memory/ or worker nodes.

```json
{
   "Error":"States.TaskFailed",
   "Cause":"{\"AllocatedCapacity\":5,\"Arguments\":{\"--quotes_col_list\":\"Null\",\"--processed_prefix\":\"processed/cat2/uber/\",\"--replicated_prefix\":\"replicated/cat2/uber/\",\"--table_folder\":\"SALES_ORDER_DOCUMENT_TYPE/\",\"--devops_prefix\":\"uber_processing/glue_configuration/rename_glue_file/replicated/uber/\",\"--tablename\":\"sales_order_document_type\",\"--companies\":\"uber\",\"--metadata_path\":\"cat2/cat2_metadata.csv\",\"--reject_prefix\":\"reject/cat2/uber/\"},\"Attempt\":0,\"CompletedOn\":1641759367801,\"ErrorMessage\":\"TooManyRequestsException: An error occurred (TooManyRequestsException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: You have exceeded the limit for the number of queries you can run concurrently. Please reduce the number of concurrent queries submitted by this account. Contact customer support to request a concurrent query limit increase.\",\"ExecutionTime\":51,\"GlueVersion\":\"2.0\",\"Id\":\"jr_b8haonpeno503no0n3020
\",\"JobName\":\"uber_job\",\"JobRunState\":\"FAILED\",\"LastModifiedOn\":1641759367801,\"LogGroupName\":\"/aws-glue/jobs\",\"MaxCapacity\":5.0,\"NumberOfWorkers\":5,\"PredecessorRuns\":[],\"StartedOn\":1641759312689,\"Timeout\":2880,\"WorkerType\":\"G.1X\"}"
}
```

When I checked the query funtion it doesn't show me any query running in glue job.

```
response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString='msck repair table '+args['audit_table'],
    ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': args['athena_resultpath'] }
)
```

Can someone help me in `QueryString='msck repair table '+args['audit_table']` what is the argument?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the word "concurrency" bit didn't mentioned exactly what the error message is:

> "ErrorMessage":"**TooManyRequestsException**: An error occurred (TooManyRequestsException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: You have **exceeded the limit** for the number of queries you can run concurrently

Athena has some built in [soft limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html), it also mentions in their docs:

> A DML or DDL query quota includes both running and queued queries. For example, if you are using the default DML quota and your total of running and queued queries exceeds 25, query 26 **will result in a TooManyRequestsException** error.

You are simply going over the limits so your query fails, specifically the "DML query quota" i'm assuming, these soft limits are somewhat flexible and can be increased by submitting a reqest via the [service quotas console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#!/services/athena/quotas)

Comment: could you please relate it to msck repair table, what is inside this string, so its crossing the limit?

Comment: >DDL query quota – 20 DDL active queries. DDL queries include CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION queries.

this is the relevant soft limit.